# What's this +(CCScene *) scene for?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

A lot of example CCLayer subclasses I see have code that looks like this:

```
+(CCScene *) scene{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
    [scene addChild: layer];

    return scene;
}
```

Who calls that method and what purpose does it serve? Does it need to be there? Is it convenient for some future purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is needed. This method is called in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of ApplicationDelegate. For example in the HellowWorld template it is called in this line in AppDelegate:
`[[director_ pushScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]]`

The ccDirector can run only CCScene, and it can run only one CCScene at a time. That is why CCLayer creates a CCScene first and then adds itself as a child to it. 
As an alternative, you can subclass `CCScene` and add your `CCLayers` and etc to it by overriding its `init` method like this:

```
-(id) init {
   if (self = [super init]){
     CCLayer *aLayer = [CCLayer node];
     [self addChild: aLayer];
     ....
  }
 return self;
}
```

and replace this line `[[director_ pushScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]]` with this `[[director_ pushScene: [myScene node]]` in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of AppDelegate.

Comment: No not really. You can do [[director_ pushScene: [SomeLayer node]] too, just that the template chooses to use the scene method. CCNode, CCLayer, CCScene is practically the same class (read comment in CCScene.h) and you can run layers without scenes.

Answer (score 0):

All I know is that it isn't needed, I've wondered the same thing. I think it is because they want to encourage the use of scenes a bit. Your scenes should consist of layers and you should switch between scenes.